# jsPDF add image issue when opening with adobe Acrobat reader

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, acrobat

On click of a button, I am creating a PDF, adding image and text to it, and then saving it to disk.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [1600, 1000]);

var img = new Image;
img.src = 'http://localhost:29576/Images/logo.png';
img.src = logoUrl;

pdf.addImage(img, 10, 10)
pdf.save();
```

Now everything works fine and I am able to view this from Chrome. But the moment , I open this from Acrobat Reader, I get an error:

> There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (110)

[image]

Comment: @Bharata, your answer is not the solutiion and not even correct up to certian extent. We don't need to do on image load , as it works withoutit and specially when dealing with large number of images as the call back will always execute before loading the image. I fixed the issue by seting compression level , https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1036

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

- you write `img.src = ...` two times. In second case you overwrites the first value;
- you have to wait until the image was loaded. This means you have to add + save the image only after event `onload`.

**The solution**

```js
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [1600, 1000]),
    img = new Image,
    logoUrl = 'http://localhost:29576/Images/logo.png';

img.onload = function()
{
    pdf.addImage(img, 10, 10);
    pdf.save('example.pdf');
};
img.src = logoUrl;
```

Comment: Ok, I had seen this solution. But how does then it work when opening with chrome and does not open when opening with adobe acrobat?

Comment: @Simsons, I do not understand: which solution does not work in Akrobat Reader? My solution or your solution? Or may be you want only know why your solution does not work with Akrobat Reader? Does my solution work?